# Subordinate Clause Without Subject

Tags: subordinate-clause

I'm struggling to translate

Every player has landed on the moon, searching for resources.

What is the grammar construction to be used here after the comma? If there isn't a subject in the dependent clause because it's referencing something from the first clause can I just leave it out?

Comment: Isn't this rather a question about the English language?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach I was wondering whether there was a german parallel and if it had a name with special rules : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, you can use almost the same construction as in the orignal sentence:

> Alle Spieler sind auf dem Mond gelandet, nach Bodenschätzen suchend.

Although this is grammatically correct, today nobody talks or writes like this. It sounds a bit like Goethe's *Und an dem Ufer steh ich lange Tage,
das Land der Griechen mit der Seele suchend.*

There are several better ways to express this in German. One is:

> Alle Spieler sind auf der Suche nach Bodenschätzen auf dem Mond gelandet.

If you don't like the double *auf*, Janka's sugestion *... um nach Bodenschätzen zu suchen* is a good alternative.

Comment: "A better way" is relative. In certain contexts, the "nach Bodenschätzen suchend" version may be better, e.g. in certain types of poetic texts. You rather meant: "in common language and everyday situations".

Answer (score 2):

*Every player has landed on the moon, searching for resources.*

The English subordinate clause gives a reason, this can be translated into German in different ways:

> Jeder der Spieler ist auf dem Mond gelandet, **um** nach Bodenschätzen **zu suchen**.

A subordinate clause with *um … zu* is the typical way to give a reason.

> Jeder der Spieler ist **zum Suchen** nach Bodenschätzen auf dem Mond gelandet.

Instead of a clause, the action *suchen* may be turned into a noun and the reason is given as a prepositional object with *zu*+dative or *wegen*+genitive.

---

A more free, but much better sentence however would be

> Alle Spieler sind wegen der Bodenschätze zum Mond aufgebrochen.

That is because the reason "searching for resources" is clearly not connected to the action of landing but it was the incentive for the whole trip.

Comment: *Alle Spieler ... sind aufgebrochen* means the players left for the moon. That's a bit different from *every player has landed on the moon*.

Comment: Ich würde eher, statt dem 2. markierten Text, schreiben "Jeder der Spieler ist zur Suche nach Bodenschätzen auf dem Mond gelandet." oder "Jeder der Spieler ist bei der Suche nach Bodenschätzen auf dem Mond gelandet." Das "der" sehe ich in der Frage auch nicht ("Jeder (der) Spieler"). "Jeder Spieler landete auf dem Mond, Bodenschätze zu suchen." wäre vielleicht am nächsten an einer noch erträglichen Wort-für-Wort-Übersetzung, geschmeidig empfände ich "Jeder Spieler landete, um Bodenschätze zu suchen, auf dem Mond."